# WP / Elementor Intercept Form and Redirect with Data

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-hook, elementor

I have a form built in Elementor that I am looking to intercep, process the data and forward onto a third party then subsequently show the data on a "confirm" card.

I am able to build this whole process as a single page, setting each as display none with CSS then showing / hiding with JS as I receive AJAX responses. This isn't ideal as it breaks with JS turned off.

I haven't been able to find the right Elementor hook and way to populate a new page with PHP, has anyone had experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few methods to POST data to another url from an Elementor web form.

One is using many of the API integrations such as Mailchimp, ActiveCampaign, Zapier etc. (see https://docs.elementor.com/article/281-form-faq) and (https://docs.elementor.com/category/405-integrations)

Another (very limited method) is by using the form's Action after Submit and choosing "redirect" and then using each field's short code as individual data strings in the url such as:

mysite.com/thank-you?fname=[field id="fname"]&lname=[field id="lname"]

You can even build your /thank-you/ page in Elementor to GET that data and populate Elementor elements such as text, title, links etc with the form field data.  For example, I could drop a text element on the /thank-you/ page and choose dynamic instead of typing in the text area and from the dynamic drop down, choose "request parameter" and for the "type" choose GET and for the param name use your unique url keys such as fname, lname etc.  You can even set prefix, suffix and even fallback text along with it.

Lastly, here is a write up on how to back end code passing data externally (https://developers.elementor.com/forms-api/#Form_New_Record_Action).

```
// A send custom WebHook
add_action( 'elementor_pro/forms/new_record', function( $record, $handler ) {
    //make sure its our form
    $form_name = $record->get_form_settings( 'form_name' );

    // Replace MY_FORM_NAME with the name you gave your form
    if ( 'MY_FORM_NAME' !== $form_name ) {
        return;
    }

    $raw_fields = $record->get( 'fields' );
    $fields = [];
    foreach ( $raw_fields as $id => $field ) {
        $fields[ $id ] = $field['value'];
    }

    // Replace HTTP://YOUR_WEBHOOK_URL with the actuall URL you want to post the form to
    wp_remote_post( 'HTTP://YOUR_WEBHOOK_URL', [
        'body' => $fields,
    ]);
}, 10, 2 );
```

And a thread with many more examples integrating with different APIs using that template as a primer (https://github.com/elementor/elementor/issues/2397)